# Does "would have to" indicate the past, present, or future?

Tags: grammar

Does "would have to" indicate the past, present, or future? What is the difference between "would have to" and "would have had to"?

1. To meet the challenge the public authority would have to be transformed into a public limited company. ( I think here it indicates "future")
2. But he said there would have to be a complete overhaul of the electoral system first. (Here it indicates past)
3. I think all the girls in the anime are awesome, but my favorites would have to be Nozomi and Umi! ( I can't understand what it indicates here)
4. As for the difference in meaning, I’d have to say it’s very subtle. ( I think here it indicates present)
5. It's not something I want to do, but it's something I'd have to do". (I think here it indicates past)
6. If he asked me to fix his car, I would have to do it tomorrow. ( here it indicates future)
7. It would not be something you'd have to do forever. (I think it indicates future)

8."Sorry, that's above my pay grade" is another way of saying this "you don't pay me enough to do X". But, as it's a lot more formal than "you don't pay me enough to do X" one would have to be careful of one's tone: as Karim said, it's jokey. (I think it indicates future)

Comment: It's always the future relative to the time it's being said. All of the contexts you're putting the phrase into are just causing to confuse you. If last year I said *it will happen tomorrow*, "tomorrow" still happened almost a year ago, but at the time I uttered the statement, it was still a future statement. The same is true of *would have to*.